# Simple countdown using minutes and seconds

Tags: javascript, refresh, countdown, seconds

I need a countdown that will refresh a page, and I think I've finally got it, except for one thing. I'd like the countdown to be in minutes and seconds, not just seconds (the countdown is for one hour). A simple MM:SS format would be fine, but also writing out minutes and seconds would work. Can anybody help?

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!--
var counterobj = document.all ? counter : document.getElementById("counter");

var countdownfrom = 3600;   //countdown period in seconds
var currentsecond = counterobj.innerHTML = countdownfrom+1; 

function countdown()
{
if (currentsecond!=1)
{
currentsecond-=1;
counterobj.innerHTML = currentsecond;
}
else
{
self.location.reload();
return;
}
setTimeout("countdown()",1000)
}

countdown()
//-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Calculate minutes using a floor doing like

```
minute = Math.floor(currentsecond/60);
```

Then just output as normal.

edit -- fixed! Hopefully! (accidentally said to use mod -- you need to use Floor, I believe)